# Programmatically deploy database project in Visual Studio (for testing)

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, testing, deployment

We have a micro service solution that includes:

- A SQL Server database project
- A Service project
- A Test project

We are interested to know if there is a programmatic way, ideally in C# to deploy the database project to a specified target server to enable us to seed and then run a set of API -> database tests. This is to aid both developer and CI/CD testing.

We have explored in memory and SQLite substitution options but ideally want to run tests as representative of production as possible to avoid the potential for the "quirks" of those solutions resulting in problems being missed.

Comment: The best way is to start by deattaching the database from the server and then make copies of the database (a mdf file).  Than you can attach the copies to the server so you have exact replicates of the database.  You can attach the copies to a server under new names so you can have more than one copy of the database on a server.  Deattach and Reattach can be done programmable in c#. Connecting to different server is just changing the connection string.  The mdf files must be located physically on the machine where SQL Server is located.  So the copies must be move to remote machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac`.

For my usage, I create the UnitTesting database separately as an empty database, then run the Database project against this database.

```
DacServices instance = new DacServices(connectionString);
String path = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\..\DatabaseProjectFolder\bin\Debug\DatabaseProject.dacpac");

String databaseName = $"UnitTesting";

using (DacPackage dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(path))
{
    instance.Deploy(dacPackage, databaseName);
}
```

Comment: Perfect - Thanks! - A side note for other readers, it seems to be the package Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx that is required. There is a none Microsoft package under the namespace name.